# 2018 Honor 10 Lite/HRY-AL00, DOESN'T CHARGE USB data works fine, ADB works fine

Tags: adb, usb, charging

Not sure how the brand of the phone really helps, but from what I gathered:

- Phone doesn't have a fast charge protocol. **Very basic micro-B USB.** Supports any 5V-1A USB charger. 3400mAh battery. The OS version is Android 10.
- A while ago no cable would charge the Phone. I took it to a repair shop, and they replaced the charging port. I bought a new cable (specced for 2A), and found no issue for a while. This didn't last long.
- **Currently no cable will charge it normally anymore.**
- May have physical damage, as I have to twist the Phone-side plug hard for the Phone to respond.
- If the phone is connected to a USB wall plug, the Phone still says it is charging, which normally has never occurred. Indicated battery percentage does not go up.
- If the Phone is connected to a PC over USB, with USB debug mode turned on, PC side `adb shell dumpsys battery` returns a growing "charge counter" (uAh) but decreasing "level" (percentage). SOMETIMES the percentage may go up, but it's not guaranteed. The USB session is generally stable.
- I have no USB multimeter yet, so no other info can be inferred from any charge session.

How should I troubleshoot this issue? Is the charging IC in the Phone somehow faulty?

Comment: Sounds like a broken soldering point on the connection between USB socket and mainboard of the phone. If only one connection soldering point of +5V or GNC is broken data may work as before but charging does not. The USB socket is very vulnerable to force when the plug is inserted, therefore I recommend to handle the phone with extreme care for people who want to keep their phone in a working state.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that you have to twist the connector at the phone, it almost certainly means that either the connector is damaged or the electrical connection to the pcb is damaged (broken solder or connector wire).

Take it back to the same repair shop (under warranty), perhaps they did not solder the new port properly.